# java does not exit back to prompt when running jar file fails

Tags: linux, jar, java, rhel

when running `java -jar myfile.jar` on my RHEL 64 machine, if the install fails for some reason, i don't get back to prompt - thus the process doesn't exit

on other RHEL 64 machine, when running the same jar file, if it fails, i get back to prompt.

both machines are running the same version of java 1.6.0_25

anyone know what can cause this behavior ?

edit: the jar has an ant build xml that fails right on the beginning (i've added `<fail/>` task).
when running the file i get this

```
Total time: 1 second
validate failed
org.tp23.antinstaller.InstallException: Error running the install, Ant run failed - examine the error logs for details
        at org.tp23.antinstaller.runtime.exe.AntLauncherFilter.exec(AntLauncherFilter.java:112)
        at org.tp23.antinstaller.runtime.exe.AntLauncherValidateFilter.exec(AntLauncherValidateFilter.java:53)
        at org.tp23.antinstaller.runtime.ExecInstall.exec(ExecInstall.java:89)
        at org.tp23.antinstaller.selfextract.SelfExtractor.main(SelfExtractor.java:372)
Install failed
Error running the install, Ant run failed - examine the error logs for details
Failed
```

but no prompt, process still running...

Comment: Are you sure the install is failing? how do you know? Do you have some error logged on some file?

Comment: MarcoS: i know it fails because i wrote it and i've specifically told it to fail to try to understand why it doesn't exit. besides, running the same file on different machines DOES exit the program thus it has to be environment related issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could it be that you still have some non-daemon threads sticking around? Try getting a Java stack dump with:

```
kill -QUIT <process_id>
```

Comment: Simon: running `java -jar myfile.jar` runs the file in a new JVM right ? so why in one environment it closes the thread and in my environment it doesn't ?

Comment: Simon: runnning what you told me yields this: http://pastebin.com/wt21r7ZZ . process still running

Comment: @michael: that's hard to answer unless we know **which** thread causes the code to continue running. `jstack` does the same thing and is possibly easier to use, btw.

Comment: There's still the AWT thread running, which means that there's still some AWT component that's referenced and/or visible.

Comment: @Joachim i am running this on a remote server with SSH. now that you mention AWT, it's possible that since i am using Xmanager to redirect screen output to my local PC, maybe it's still running, i will check to see if this is the problem

Comment: okay i've confirmed it, i used `setenv DISPLAY` to redirect screen output to my PC so Xmanager could put it on my screen. even though the installation was running in silent mode, i guess it was still using on the screen. now that i have disabled the `setenv DISPLAY` it is failing okay and throws me back to the prompt like it should.